# Can I give access to state variable?

Tags: solidity

There is setData variable. This is Struct array variable. Now, anyone can access data contents in setData. So, I want to add access restriction to setData. I want to make access setData only by owner. Is that possible?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

address owner;

function SimpleStorage() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    if (msg.sender != owner)
        throw;
    _;
}

struct Sample {
    uint256 id;
    string data;
}

uint256 public id;
Sample[] public setData; // ← I want to add "onlyOwner" modifier. Can I do it?
function set(string data) {
    setData.push(Sample({
        id: id,
        data: data
    }));
    id++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your question is not clear. if you want that only owner sets Data (setData) so remove the public type from : Sample[] public setData;
and use the modifier in set function.

uint256 public id;

```
Sample[]  setData;  

function set(string data) onlyOwner {
    setData.push(Sample({
        id: id,
        data: data
    }));
    id++;
}
```

otherwise if you want that only the owner access the setData array so write your own getter :

```
function get(uint i) onlyOwner internal returns (Sample)  {
   return setData[i];

}
```

Comment: I want to make a storage. It has the function of storing data in struct type and getting that data. Therefore, I added the public keyword to the setData variable. Because otherwise, I can not get an array of struct type.
The getter function that you taught can not be called from public, so I do not think it will function as storage. Even if data can be stored, data can not be got.
By the way, the reason for using struct type for data storage is that you can include multiple types in it.

Comment: Can I get the setData from public, not using public keyword?

Comment: Are you trying to make it so a) anyone can set and only the contract owner can retrieve the values, or b) anyone can set and only the person who stored a value can get it back? Matthew is correct. Visibility of the state variables doesn't alter the fact that the state is accessible by anyone. Nothing will be truly private.

Comment: I am trying to make a). The above thing you taught me,, get function do not call() because of internal keyword. Can I call get function in public ?

Answer (score 1):

To add, while it's true you can remove `public` from setData to hide it from other contracts, it only hides it from *other contracts.*

It's not possible to prevent access from the outside world (i.e. anyone with a Ethereum node). The state of every variable is public knowledge--otherwise, it'd be impossible to run or verify transactions.

Comment: Note that in theory it doesn't even hide it from other contracts very well, since you can always use a merkle proof to prove to another contract that a particular value is in storage